# Generate listview from JSON in android without Main node?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Is posible to make a listview from JSON without the main node.
I get this json object from a REST
My json string is

```
[{"productName": "prod1", "category": "cat1"},
{"productName": "prod2", "category": "cat1"},
{"productName": "prod3", "category": "cat2"},
{"productName": "prod4", "category": "cat1"}]
```

But it doesn't have a main node like `{ "products": [ ... ] }`

how do I parse that into a list view without the main node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Suppose you are using `Gson` as serialiser. So your entity should look like this

```
public class Product {

@SerializedName("productName")
@Expose
private String productName;
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private String category;

public String getProductName() {
return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
this.productName = productName;
}

public String getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

}
```

So use List< Product > to deserialise json to list of objects.